# Jquery .data() issues storing and retrieving data

Tags: jquery

I am having a simple issues with this example and getting the "a is null" in the Firefox error console. No alert shows. If I change from a DOM element to a object it works?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('<div>').attr('id', 'test').appendTo('#ii').text('dfdfd');
    $('#test').data({'rr': 'data', 'tt': 55});
    alert($.param($('#test').data()));
   });
 </script>
    <html>
     <head>

    </head>
   <body>
       <div id="ii"></div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why do you expect data to be attached to `#ii` when you explicitly attached it to `#test` instead?

Comment: Type in example, fixed above.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2NTts/ Are you sure you're running the code after the DOM is ready?

Comment: With Jquery we are talking about document.ready ?

Comment: I have updated the code, no alert and still getting the a is null error.

Comment: That's because you changed `.attr('id', 'test')` to `.attr('id', 'alf')`, and now there's no `$('#test')` to inspect. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/2NTts/1/ Your code is fine, your selectors are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you meant to get the data from `#test` rather than `#ii`:

```
$('<div>').attr('id', 'test').appendTo('#ii').text('some text');
$('#test').data({'ob1': 'some', 'ob2': 55});
alert($.param($('#test').data()));
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/okiwan/edit#javascript,html,live)

If this is not working it is likely that an element with the id `#ii` does not exist.